# weird characters in Terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

When I try to run command in ubuntu I get the garbage characters appear on command line. 
Please look at the image the line of characters are repetation [[-^ repeating it many times. How do I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Does this happen with any command or is it a particular key that causes it? Do you have a file called `$HOME/.inputrc`? If yes, please post it here. You are logged in as `root` in the image above (so why are you using `sudo`?), does this happen with your normal user too?

Comment: Yes it happens randomly with any commands, I dont have .inputrc files. It also happens before starting ubuntu.

Comment: It also happens with any version of ubuntu or linux, for exeample it also happen with ubuntu LTS and saucy release..

Comment: This is probably a problem with your keyboard. Sounds like you have a stuck key. Try cleaning your keyboard or using a different one.

Comment: Problem was with my keybord

Answer (score 4):

The kind of output you are showing is normally due to a stuck key on your keyboard, you can test by using another one. Specifically, the `^[[2~` sequence is sent by <kbd>Insert</kbd>. So, you almost certainly have that particular key stuck.

You can try cleaning the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key, you can take the key cap off and clean behind it. If cleaning makes no difference, you will probably need to change keyboards.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the command `reset`.

`reset - terminal initialization`

check http://linux.die.net/man/1/reset or type `man reset` for more info.

---

You can also reset your terminal through the "Terminal"->"Reset" menu.

Comment: This is not really relevant to the problem, reset will clear the screen but the issue will continue.